# Websocket server using Netbeans and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, websocket

I'm having trouble accessing a websocket server using Netbeans and Tomcat 8.0.9 (Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404).  Here is my java code:

```
package WebSocketServer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.websocket.Session;

@javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")
public class WebSocketServer {
    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());    

    @javax.websocket.OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message) {
        return null;
    }

    @javax.websocket.OnOpen
    public void onOpen (Session peer) {
        peers.add(peer);
    }

    @javax.websocket.OnClose
    public void onClose (Session peer) {
        peers.remove(peer);
    }    
}
```

javascript:

```
var wsUri = "ws://" + document.location.host + "/WebSocketServer/endpoint";

var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

function onError(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
}

// For testing purposes
var output = document.getElementById("output");
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };

function writeToScreen(message) {
    output.innerHTML += message + "<br>";
}

function onOpen() {
    writeToScreen("Connected to " + wsUri);
}
// End test functions
```

I am using Java EE7 and read there were some issues with Tomcat 7 but that these have been resolved with Tomcat 8?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 404 indicates that the resource was not found. Therefore the requested URI has to be faulty.